# Zend rpc json return array

Tags: php, arrays, json, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Hi there I have a small problem i can't figure out. Im writing a RPC service using ZendFramework and Apigility. The response must be a json array. Next comes all the content negotiation code.

```
'controllers' => array(
        'NmdaWebApi\\V1\\Rpc\\Hola\\Controller' => 'Json',

'accept_whitelist' => array(
        'NmdaWebApi\\V1\\Rpc\\Hola\\Controller' => array(
            0 => 'application/vnd.nmda-web-api.v1+json',
            1 => 'application/json',
            2 => 'application/*+json',
        ),
'content_type_whitelist' => array(
        'NmdaWebApi\\V1\\Rpc\\Hola\\Controller' => array(
            0 => 'application/json',
        ),
```

This is how I have the controller

```
class HolaController extends AbstractActionController{
        public function holaAction(){
                return array(1,2,3,4,5);}}
```

And here is the returned json.

```
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5}
```

I'm getting this list and a I want an array. Here is another example.

```
return array(1,2,3,4,array(5,6,7));
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":[5,6,7]}
```

Can someone explain me how to avoid this?

**Edit_1**

I figured out a workaround. Using HalJson fixes the problem. But i still cant understand why it doesnt work with normal Json.

```
'controllers' => array(
        'NmdaWebApi\\V1\\Rpc\\Hola\\Controller' => 'HalJson',
```

Comment: if it suits you try to return array('ids' => array(1,2,3,4,5)); 
than you will have your array but in key "ids"

Comment: mmm not rly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action you must return a JsonModel. To do that, first create a 'strategies' key under your 'view_manager' section in your module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'strategies'                => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
),
```

Now you can return a JsonModel in your action:

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

return new JsonModel([
    'data' => $data
]);
```

Comment: I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Returning JsonModel from my Controller class work. I just use it like this.             return new JsonModel($data);.